# Lein tasks and sudo

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I'd like to get this running (https://github.com/maitria/avi), which recommends using

```
sudo lein install
```

But lein doesn't act like an ordinary command -- I get

```
sudo: lein: command not found.
```

There only seem to be three subcommands that run into permissions problems and I considered doing them manually, but they're fairly gnarly string-interpolated arguments to the C compiler and my chances of not making a mistake seem pretty small.

Answer (score 0):

So leiningen is not your typical command. Its a tool built in Clojure and is used to manage clojure applications much like rake works for Ruby. These 3 steps should help you

1. Download the lien script from the [leiningen home page](http://leiningen.org/) and place it in a location that is part of your PATH.

2.Run `lein` in the command-line and it will install it dependencies, though you will need to make sure you preinstalled JDK

3.Run `lein install` in the location of your code

Comment: Following these basic instructions, I am still getting:

-bash: lein: command not found